# It is possible to track back how many cells are merged with TEXTJOIN [Excel]?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, merge

I am combining multiple values into a cell in `Excel` using `TEXTJOIN`

This is the dummy dataset (the actual dataset contains thousands of entries, and each entries contains hundreds of characters so it is quite difficult to manually count how many entries are merged:

[image]

In the dataset above, it is quite easy to detect that each of `Team 1` and `Team 2` contain 4 entries. It is possible to count how many entries are merged automatically?

Thanks in advance

#p.s.: I am using Excel Online so I am unable to use VBA to solve my problem

Answer (score 1):

Your entries are separated by commas. So you just need to count the number of commas, then add 1 to get the number of entries. The `+ 1`

For the example you have given, on F1 enter the following formula:

```
=LEN(E1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(E1,",","")) + 1
```

on F2 enter the following formula:

```
=LEN(E2)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(E2,",","")) + 1
```

The `+ 1` also ensures that if there is only one entry, you get the correct result.

In case there are conditions that return no values, change the formula to:

```
=IF(LEN(E)>0,LEN(E1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(E1,",","")) + 1,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You use `$B$2:$B$9=1` within your `TextJoin`.  You could also use it within a `COUNTIF`.

`=COUNTIF($B$2:$B$9,1)` will return 4.

Rather than hardcoded your team number you could place just the number in cells `D1:D2` and give it a custom number format of `"Team " #`.
Then use `=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,IF($B$2:$B$9=$D1,$A$2:$A$9,""))` and `=COUNTIF($B$2:$B$9,$D1)` and drag down for each team.

Answer (score 0):

Try this formula:

```
=TEXTJOIN(",",,FILTER($A$2:$A$9,($B$2:$B$9=NUMBERVALUE((RIGHT(D2,1))))))
```

[image]